# ECL item 'ecl:1262-cel-226-cea-file' not found

Tags: dxa, web8.5, ecl, tbb, dxa-1.8

I'm working on an ECL integration for Web 8.5 right now. My plan is to resolve the ECL components with my own TBB. However, I cannot even publish a page using the default DXA TBB.

"Generate Dynamic Page (DXA)" throws an error when trying to resolve my ECL component.

```
ComponentBuilder: start BuildComponent with component ecl:0-cel-226-cea-file (tcm:1262-422810) and link level 49
EclProcessor: Retrieving ECL item for ECL Stub Component: tcm:1262-422810
ECL item 'ecl:1262-cel-226-cea-file' not found (TCM URI: 'tcm:1262-422810')
   at DD4T.Templates.Base.Utils.EclProcessor.GetEclItem(String eclStubComponentId, IContentLibraryContext& eclContext)
```

Am I missing something here?

Page Template contains:

```
 - Generate Dynamic Page (DXA)
 - Resolve Rich Text
```

Component Template for this component contains:

```
- Resolve ECL items V2
- Generate Dynamic Component (DXA)
- Publish binaries for component
- Resolve Rich Text
```

I can open the TCM-ID and the ECL-ID in the CMS, they both exist.

Thanks

Kind regards

Arne

Comment: Welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange, looks like this item tcm:1262-422810 does not exist in cms, double check that ECL item in that component linked it exists or not try to open that item to see? please edit your question to update what are the TBBs added in your component template and page template, is that ECL folder displays correctly on your pages level publication is it working as expected?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i can open the TCM-ID

/WebUI/item.aspx?tcm=16#id=tcm:1262-422810

and the ECL-ID

/WebUI/item.aspx?ecl=file#id=ecl:1262-cel-226-cea-file

in Tridion. They both exists and look fine.

The ECL folder also looks fine in the publication.

Comment: please edit your question to specify what is your DXA version?

Comment: Done, its 1.8..

Comment: Link Level 49 ?! Is that *really* needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have not added **Resolve ECL items V2** to your Component Template TBB.

In the template builder folder, you can see **SDL External Content Library** and named **Resolve ECL items V2**. Add this to your Component Template and it will deal with the ECL item.

I hope it helps.

Comment: ECL was installed with Web 8.5 but there is no "SDL External Content Library" folder in the template builder.

Comment: Ok sorry, i needed to create the default TBBs in the Template Builder, will add the V2 TBB now..

Comment: Added the TBB "Resolve ECL items V2" to the Component Template but the error did not change

Comment: Ok i needed to restart the template builder, error is actually resolved. Thank you.

Comment: If all is well, the “Resolve ECL items V2” TBB should *not* be required for DXA; you can see in the error message that DD4T templates will resolve links to ECL Stub Components anyways. I don’t know why you got that error, though. Can you check if it re-occurs if you remove the “Resolve ECL items” TBB again?

Comment: Also check out Jonathan’s Answer; it can explain why things all of the sudden start working (and later magically break again).

Comment: The TBB was not required, it was my mistake in the first place. I needed to restart the template builder to actually load the changes i made to the ECL integration. I was not aware of it since i dont need to restart when making changes to templates. Confusing..

Answer (score 7):

If your Publisher is outscaled onto a separate Windows server, then you'll need to make sure that the ECL mountpoints are configured correctly on that server too.

I've been caught-out by that before!

P.S. You'll need to restart the *SDL Publisher* Windows Service after making the change.