# cannot resolve Component Link to EclItem in Rich Text Field

Tags: dxa, ecl, dxa2.2

Tridion 9. 1 DXA 2.2  Component Link to EclItem in Rich Text Field cannot resolve.
Example:

```
<a title="abc" href="ecl:11-bynder-1DCC6C05!2D;0C7D!2D;4B93!2D;9D94D25AD6CC445F-Bynder!5F;image-file">abc</a>
```

preview:

```
<a title="abc" href="/image/19-bynder-2DCC6C05%212D%3B0C7D%212D%3B4B93%212D%3B9D94D25AD6CC445F-Bynder%215F%3Bimage-file_tcm11-111.ecl">abc</a>
```

Link not resolving the real ECL url. Resolve ECL items V2 included in Component Template.
Img component link works, but not a link, Any Solution to Solve the Issue?

Comment: Please refer to this link for some related information on ecl and linking https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/18894/401

Comment: hi Anand resolve elites v2 is added to template but link not resolved.

Comment: DXA has built-in support for ECL Items; the “Resolve ECL Items V2” TBB should not be used.  Please check whether `EclModelBuilder` is configured (in the “Render Page Content” TBB). See https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/blob/master/Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.R2/Data/EclModelBuilder.cs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, only MM Component links (incl. ECL Item links) in `img` elements in Rich Text Fields are processed by DXA.

However, as of DXA 2.2, this is configurable. See section “Embedding” in the [What’s New for DXA 2.2](https://docs.sdl.com/784837/748407/sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-2/changes-introduced-in-------------sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-2)

Note that the “Resolve ECL Items V2” TBB should *not* be used in DXA TBBs; DXA has built-in support for ECL.

Comment: thanks for the direction, in the doc "list the Schema identifiers of the Component Schemas that you want to expand", can i put <a> in parameter or can you give me an example. thanks again.

Comment: As Schema identifier you can use: the Schema’s Namespace URI, a combination of Namespace URI and Root Element Name (separated by a colon), or the Schema’s Title.

Comment: thanks Rick solution works